# O botão de proteger perguntas não está aparecendo?

Tags: suporte, bug, privilégios

O botão de [proteger perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) não me está aparecendo, veja a imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sup>[Os "Class Components" morreram no React?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/438395/137387)</sup>

O mesmo me acontece com outras perguntas no site principal e também aqui no META.

Não é uma ferramenta que eu use sempre mas é bom saber se estou bloqueado de a usar ou se é bug do sistema?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Segundo o [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52764/401803):

> *can protect a question which is at least a day old, has at least one answer by a new user (i.e. a user that currently has <10 rep on the site), and is not locked*

Ou seja, para que a pergunta possa ser protegida, ela deve ter sido feita há mais de um dia, ter pelo menos uma resposta de um usuário com reputação menor que 10 e não pode estar bloqueada.

No caso, a pergunta em questão não satisfaz o segundo critério, por isso não pode ser protegida ([exceto por moderadores](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276978/401803)).

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu tempo!

Comment: @AugustoVasques O [link do help](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) tá precisando de uma boa melhoria, no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) está bem melhor. Não só esse que precisa de melhoria, tem alguns outros também. Vou checar se tem algo haver com as traduções, caso não seja, podemos abrir uma solicitação de melhoria aqui no META mesmo :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, como que funcionaria essa solicitação de melhorias da [central de ajuda](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/help)? Seria um como um debate onde cada usuário responde propondo uma sugestão para um link especifico ou para cada link da central de ajuda seria feita uma solicitação? Já houve esse tipo de debate?

Comment: @AugustoVasques [Eu já fiz isso uma vez](/q/7170/112052): eu sugeri um texto, não houve objeções, e depois tive que pedir para um dos CM's atualizar. Não sei se mudou algo, mas pelo que vi do [histórico](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=central+de+ajuda+) parece ser o caminho usual...